# How to compare HTML markup with symbols in Cypress

Tags: cypress, chai

I am trying to check the contents of an element that has a squareroot sign ( √ ) with the Cypress

```
.should('have.html', html)
```

construction, but it fails the comparison and it is not clear why.

[image: Screenshot from Cypress]

Answer (score 0):

Answered by Cypress [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/15800).

Workaround is to just type the symbol in to the source as text:

```
cy.get('#y-value')
  // use the text value of the HTML entity
  .should('have.html', '√y')
  // "have.html", "have.text", and "contain"
  // assertions work the same with text
  .and('have.text', '√y')
  .and('contain', '√y')
```